# How to enable Android Ip forwarding

Tags: iptables

In linux we can,

```
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

or,

```
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

There is no `sysctl` command nor `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` file in Android. 
Is there an equivalent operation in Android?

Comment: Which Android version are you using? My Android 4.2.1 has that file. `sysctl` can be obtained by installing Busybox.

Answer (score 1):

This method worked for me, I just setup android as proxy server and need enable forwarding

**Use ROOT explorer and EDIT this file:** ***/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward***

**add this syntax:**

```
iptables -F -t filter

iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

if that file not found, try install busybox first.. but I guess that file by default is available on android system.